# How to setup Facebook Redex in order to optimize Android Bytecodes?

Tags: android, facebook, redex, facebook-redex

There is a very good instruction in Redex page at http://fbredex.com/.

I follow the instruction but I have problem in two steps.

1.I have no problem with run of first command (my OS is Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install \
    g++ \
    automake \
    autoconf \
    autoconf-archive \
    libtool \
    libboost-all-dev \
    libevent-dev \
    libdouble-conversion-dev \
    libgoogle-glog-dev \
    libgflags-dev \
    liblz4-dev \
    liblzma-dev \
    libsnappy-dev \
    make \
    zlib1g-dev \
    binutils-dev \
    libjemalloc-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libiberty-dev
```

2. I clone [folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly) repo somewhere on my laptop
3. I go to the directory by `$ cd android/projects/folly/folly/`
4. I run `git submodule update --init` but nothing happens. I even run this command in `$ cd android/projects/folly/` but nothing happens either.
5. I run `autoreconf -ivf && ./configure && make && make install`. Seems works as I see process takes around a minute or two and there are a lot og messages print out.
6. I copy/paste a sample .apk file to my Desktop and run `redex ~/Desktop/my_android_app.apk -o ~/Desktop/my_android_app-redexed.apk`. However, I'm getting this message on terminal.

   > No command 'redex' found, did you mean:  Command 'redet' from package
   >   'redet' (universe) redex: command not found

I ran above command when I am in `/home/hesam/android/projects/folly/folly` or `/home/hesam/android/projects/folly/`. But I get same output.

## Update

I cloned [Redex](https://github.com/facebook/redex) repo and followed Bert's Instruction. It works and I could see something is happening by running `git submodule update --init`. So thanks to Bert. However, I got error at the end of `autoreconf -ivf && ./configure && make && make install` command.

Please have a look at following output:

```
Making all in unit
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/hesam/android/projects/redex/test/unit'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/hesam/android/projects/redex/test/unit'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hesam/android/projects/redex/test'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hesam/android/projects/redex'
Making install in third-party/folly/folly
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/hesam/android/projects/redex/third-party/folly/folly'
Making install in .
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/hesam/android/projects/redex/third-party/folly/folly'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/hesam/android/projects/redex/third-party/folly/folly'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libfolly.la libfollybenchmark.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libfolly.so.57.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libfolly.so.57.0.0
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libfolly.so.57.0.0': Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/hesam/android/projects/redex/third-party/folly/folly'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hesam/android/projects/redex/third-party/folly/folly'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hesam/android/projects/redex/third-party/folly/folly'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
hesam: redex (master) $ redex ~/Desktop/my_android_app.apk -o ~/Desktop/my_android_app-redexed.apk 
No command 'redex' found, did you mean:
 Command 'redet' from package 'redet' (universe)
redex: command not found
hesam: redex (master) $
```

Comment: Read the issues on Github. People have had your problem and there are answer on how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a difference regard instructions you see in [fbredex](http://fbredex.com/) and what you see in [Github redex](https://github.com/facebook/redex) page. Please follow what Github page says for `make` and `install`.

```
autoreconf -ivf && ./configure && make
sudo make install
```

Regard my above problem, A developer from Redex team called me and after few minutes he found and solved the problem. He has updated FAQ section on Redex page that you can see [at here](https://github.com/facebook/redex#im-getting-usrlocalbinredex-all-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libfollyso57). Since there is no explanation there I copy/paste what he said on chat.

> So, as an optimization, the runtime linker doesn't actually go
>   trawling through everything to look for libs anymore It uses the cache
>   file, which is generated by ldconfig

## Update

I forgot to mention that you must have `ANDROID_SDK` in your PATH. I have following paths in my `.profile`. Don't forget to `source` it after making change in it. `~/android/sdk` is path to my Android SDK directory.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK=${ANDROID_HOME}
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to separately clone folly; it's included as a submodule of redex.  Just do:

`git clone https://github.com/facebook/redex.git
cd redex
git submodule update --init`

and then configure/make according to the instructions.

Comment: Hi Bert. Thanks for your reply. You instruction helped me to fix my first problem. However, my second problem is still exist. Please have a look at update. Thanks.

Comment: 1.autoreconf -ivf && ./configure && make
2.sudo make install  run this command after the above answer command and u will get redex command recognized.